# HTML JAVASCRIPT : add random values to elements of page

Tags: javascript, html, random, checkbox

I'm a beginner in web development and I have made a website where I have a products page like this :

[image: my product page]

Now I have also made a simple button under these products . By clicking on that button using javascript you have to randomly check some of the "buy me" checkboxes of the page . If a box is checked you have to 
assign a random value between 1-5 to the amount(quantity) of the book whose box is checked . At last the sum of all these products has to be added to the orange cart I have above the books . I have written code  about this task but my problem is how to iterate through each product and randomly check a box and put a number to the amount  as when I press the button that activates this function nothing changes
My code below (Let's say I have 2 products ):

```js
  function randomfunc(){
   
    var c = document.getElementById("cart"); //get the cart
    var sum =0; //the sum of products that has to be displayed next to cart
 
 for(var i =0;i<6;i++)
 {
   var flag = Math.floor(Math.random()*0)+1; //random num between 1 and 0 
        var p = document.getElementsByClass("p-price");//get price

   var y=document.getElementsByClass("buyme").elements[i];//get the checkboxes
   var x=document.getElementsByClass("amount").elements[i].value;//get the amounts of each prod
   if(flag==0)
   {
     x=x.checked;//check the box
    y= Math.floor(Math.random()*1)+5;//assign random num to amount
  
   }
   
   else if(flag==1){
      
   x = !(x.checked); //uncheck the box if i have checked it before pressing the button 
     }
    
    sum+=y*p;
    
    
 }
 
     c.innerHTML= (sum + &euro;);
  
  
  
  
  }
```

```html
 <img src = "IMAGES/shopcart.png"  id = "cart"alt = cart/> = "" (price of selected products)  
 
<div id="p-float">

 
 <div class="p-float"><div class="p-float-in">
            <center><img class="p-img" src="IMAGES\work.jpg" alt = deepw/ ><br/>
            <div class="p-name">Deep </br>Work </div>
      <div class="p-price">$9.99</div>
   <div class = "amount"> Amount:<input type = "number" name = "num"  value = "amount " min = "1" max = "5"/> </div><br/>
            <div class = "buyme">   <input type = "checkbox" name = "box" value = "Buy me"/> Buy Me  </div></center>
     </div></div>



   <div class="p-float"><div class="p-float-in">
            <center><img class="p-img" src="IMAGES\giant.jpg" alt = gnt/ ><br/>
            <div class="p-name">Awaken the giant within</div>
      <div class="p-price">$9.99</div>
   <div class = "amount"> Amount:<input type = "number" name = "num"  value = "amount " min = "1" max = "5"/> </div><br/>
            <div class = "buyme">   <input type = "checkbox" name = "box" value = "Buy me"/> Buy Me  </div></center>
     </div></div> 



</div>

  <button class = "randbtn" onclick="randomfunc()"> Select random products </button>
```

I would appreciate your help with guiding me to solve this issue (sorry about some book titles but I don't have another page ...)

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in this section of your code:

```
  var y=document.getElementsByClass("buyme").elements[i];//get the checkboxes
  var x=document.getElementsByClass("amount").elements[i].value;//get the amounts of each prod
  if(flag==0)
  {
    x=x.checked;//check the box
      y= Math.floor(Math.random()*1)+5;//assign random num to amount

  }
```

You are trying to create new variables containing the objects/values of the accessed object which won't be references to the original object. Also it should read `getElementsByClassName` and not `getElementsByClass` (hit F12 and check the Console tab for errors).

Instead you have to directly set the properties on the DOM object:

```
if (flag===0) {
  document.getElementsByClassName('buyme')[i].checked = 'checked';
  document.getElementsByClassName('amount')[i].value= Math.floor(Math.random()*5)+1;
}
```